# Datastudio Column Name not found

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I had to transfer some of my Google BigQuery tables and now some datastudio dashboards dont work anymore. I checked the query Datastudio runs. it does this:

```
SELECT t0.column, SUM(t0.value) AS t0_qt_weezwy5dnb FROM 
(SELECT * FROM `table_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180726' AND '20180726')
 AS t0 GROUP BY t0.column ORDER BY t0.column DESC;
```

But it gives me the error "Name column not found inside t0". I have the column for sure in this one date that is in the query. There are other tables, with earlier dates, that dont have the column. However, this should not affect the result when I only look at that one date. It used to work before I re-named the tables.

Any one an idea how to solve it so works again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery uses the schema of the most recently created table that matches the wildcard as the schema for the wildcard table.
Note: WHERE clause is applied after that so schema in your case comes not from the table of the date in WHERE clause - not at all

to solve this - you can create new empty table with matching table name and with schema that you expect. of course this will work till you have yet new table created with schema that lacking that columns

so, the best way is to keep consistent schema across "family" of such tables - tables with similar names that you expect to query in such fashion using _TABLE_SUFFIX

Comment: Thanks a million! This was actually the case! Just had to add a new table with the new schema and it worked again as it used to! Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when you use `_TABLE_SUFFIX`. All tables must have the SAME schema. The query needs to compile.

So earlier tables must have 'name' as well. You can patch those tables and add 'name' to it. You can patch even tables created for you by any automatic export tool: analytics, firebase, billing export.